# No config file after installing Ansible

Tags: installation, ansible

I just installed Ansible on a RHEL8 computer:

```
python3 -m pip install --user ansible
```

Installation seems to be successful:

```
Installing collected packages: resolvelib, PyYAML, pycparser, packaging, MarkupSafe, jinja2, cffi, cryptography, ansible-core, ansible
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-2.1.2 PyYAML-6.0 ansible-7.5.0 ansible-core-2.14.5 cffi-1.15.1 cryptography-40.0.2 jinja2-3.1.2 packaging-23.1 pycparser-2.21 resolvelib-0.8.1
```

But there's no config file:

```
cbro@rhel8:~$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.14.5]
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/cbro/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/cbro/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/cbro/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/cbro/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.11.2 (main, Feb 17 2023, 09:28:16) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18)] (/usr/bin/python3)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

And `/etc/ansible` wasn't created.
What could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [The configuration file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file). The search order is:

- ANSIBLE_CONFIG (environment variable if set)
- ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
- ~/.ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
- /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

None of the above options is mandatory. There is a default configuration 'hardwired' in Ansible. The command [ansible-config](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-config.html) dumps the current configuration including the sources

```bash
shell> ansible-config dump
```

---

For example, if you create *ansible.cfg* in the current directory

```ini
shell> pwd
/export/scratch/tmp7/test-348

shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml

[colors]
changed = purple
error = red
ok = green
unreachable = bright red
warn = bright purple
```

you can dump the changes only

```ini
shell> ansible-config dump --changed-only

COLOR_CHANGED(/export/scratch/tmp7/test-348/ansible.cfg) = purple
COLOR_ERROR(/export/scratch/tmp7/test-348/ansible.cfg) = red
COLOR_OK(/export/scratch/tmp7/test-348/ansible.cfg) = green
COLOR_UNREACHABLE(/export/scratch/tmp7/test-348/ansible.cfg) = bright red
COLOR_WARN(/export/scratch/tmp7/test-348/ansible.cfg) = bright purple
CONFIG_FILE() = /export/scratch/tmp7/test-348/ansible.cfg
DEFAULT_GATHERING(/export/scratch/tmp7/test-348/ansible.cfg) = explicit
DEFAULT_HOST_LIST(/export/scratch/tmp7/test-348/ansible.cfg) = ['/export/scratch/tmp7/test-348/hosts']
DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH(/export/scratch/tmp7/test-348/ansible.cfg) = ['/export/scratch/tmp7/test-348/roles']
DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK(/export/scratch/tmp7/test-348/ansible.cfg) = yaml
DEFAULT_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE(env: ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE) = /home/admin/.vault_pass.txt
RETRY_FILES_ENABLED(/export/scratch/tmp7/test-348/ansible.cfg) = False
```

The dump comprises also *ANSIBLE_** environment variables

```ini
shell> set | grep ANSIBLE
ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=/home/admin/.vault_pass.txt
```

---

If you [install Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#pip-install) by *pip* as *--user* you don't want to rewrite the system-wide configuration */etc/ansible/ansible.cfg* that might be used by other users. Instead, you might want to create *~/.ansible.cfg* or set environment *ANSIBLE_CONFIG* for this particular user.

Quoting from [Getting the latest configuration](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_configuration.html#getting-the-latest-configuration):

> If installing Ansible from a package manager, the latest ansible.cfg file should be present in /etc/ansible, possibly as a .rpmnew file (or other) as appropriate in the case of updates.

> If you installed Ansible from pip or from source, you may want to create this file in order to override default settings in Ansible.

Some distributions install *ansible.cfg* from a package

```bash
shell> apt-file list ansible | grep etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
ansible: /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
shell> uname
Linux
```

some don't

```bash
shell> pkg info --list-file py38-ansible | grep etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
shell> uname
FreeBSD
```

Comment: Thank you for the instruction and reference. I was able to create the cfg file and run ansible against it.